# Why default value in sql when we use the entity framework code first is not registered

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Why default value in SQL when we use Entity Framework is not registered ?

Table code in T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Groups] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_T2_Groups]  DEFAULT (ident_current('T2')),
CONSTRAINT [PK_T2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I use Entity Framework, the default value for the `Groups` column could not be registered.

Why?

What is the solution?

class

```
public class T2
{
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public int Groups { set; get; }
}

telentity db = new telentity();
db.T2.Add(new T2()
{
   name="ali"
});
db.SaveChange();
```

Comment: If `T2.Groups` allows nulls, then `public int Groups {get;set;}` should be `public int? Groups {get;set;}`

Comment: Was corrected code sql

Answer (score 0):

I assume you always get value `0` in `Groups`, because the c# default of `integer` is `0`. Entity framework just saves the value it finds in your entity object. The database "thinks", ah, there's a value, no need to find a default myself. (After all, `0` is a value).

If you don't want EF to include the value in insert and update statements you can map it as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`.

Comment: you can Take the example of a DatabaseGeneratedOption Computed. tanks

Comment: What do you mean by "you can take"? If this was helpful to you maybe it's good to know that part of the StackOverflow citizenship is to mark helpful answers as accepted.